# Getting all country codes from libphonenumber-js and looping it out

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, country-codes, libphonenumber

I have a contact number input field and I was able to prepend a country code dropdown to the input field.

Now when user selects the country code, the number format will change according to the selected country code.

My question now is how do you loop all the country code out from the library and put it into the dropdown? I tried using some functions like "getSupportedRegions();" but it is saying undefined. I already have the script-src included in the head, am I doing it wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/libphonenumber-js@^1.7.6/bundle/libphonenumber-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <label for="inputContactNumber">Contact Number</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">

        
            <select class="select-country" class="btn contact-btn dropdown-toggle">
                <option>SG</option> 
                <option>MY</option>
                <option>US</option>
                <option>TH</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input class="input-phone phone-format" class="form-control phone-format" type="text" name="contactNo" placeholder="Enter contact number" required//>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

     $(".phone-format").keyup(function () {
            var val_old = $(this).val();
            var newString = new libphonenumber.AsYouType($(".select-country").val()).input(val_old);
            $(this).focus().val('').val(newString);
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is just a testing one actually it doesn't work. Sorry I did not mention it. I should go ahead and erase that.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know how to covert to stack overflow snippet ! :D

Comment: Found the function for you, I will delete my comments above since they're no longer relevant. Feel free to delete your comments too just to clean up the Q/A page, and then I will delete this one. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `libphonenumber.getCountries()` ([documentation](https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js#getcountries-string)).

I added a call to this function at the beginning of your script with the code to generate the country option list:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/libphonenumber-js@^1.7.6/bundle/libphonenumber-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <label for="inputContactNumber">Contact Number</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">

        
            <select class="select-country" class="btn contact-btn dropdown-toggle">
            </select>
        </div>
        <input class="input-phone phone-format" class="form-control phone-format" type="text" name="contactNo" placeholder="Enter contact number" required//>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    const countries = libphonenumber.getCountries();
    const optionList = countries.map( country => `<option>${country}</option>` );
    $(".select-country").html( optionList );

    $(".phone-format").keyup(function () {
        const val_old = $(this).val();
        const newString = new libphonenumber.AsYouType($(".select-country").val()).input(val_old);
        $(this).focus().val(newString);
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I also changed `var` to `const`. Always use `const` when you can, or `let` if you need to mutate (reassign) a variable. And a minor point, in this line:

`$(this).focus().val('').val(newString);`

You don't need to do the `val('')`, just set the new value.

Comment: Awesome!! It works like a charm. Thanks a mil :)
However, I do have a question for you, as of the current state, although when I type in the number it will be formatted automatically, but if I were to key in an extra number then the formats would be gone and all the numbers will be packed together again. Is there anything that can fix this?

Comment: Afraid I don't know the answer to that one, as I've never worked with this library before. I just got lucky on the `getCountries()` call. Maybe post it as a new question and see if anyone has any ideas?